# Teradata format string for converting string to timestamp(6)

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a columnn of timestamps stored as text with no spaces, hyphens, slashes or decimal points, e.g. `20140328160335880258`. I want to convert this text to a timestamp in Teradata (v15).

If cut off the microseconds, the following works:

```
SELECT CAST('20140328160335' AS TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'yyyymmddhhmiss')
```

However, I can't find a format string that allows the partial seconds to be included in the timestamp:

```
SELECT CAST('20140328160335880258' AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'yyyymmddhhmiss') 
> SELECT Failed. 6760: Invalid timestamp

SELECT CAST('20140328160335880258' AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'yyyymmddhhmissssssss') 
> SELECT Failed. 3350: Invalid FORMAT string
```

I've tried `'yyyymmddhhmiss.ssssss'`, `'yyyymmddhhmiss.s(6)'`, `'yyyymmddhhmisss(6)'` and `'yyyymmddhhmissffffff'`, but all are invalid.

Is the only option to insert a decimal point into the text version of the timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way using Teradata's `FORMAT` without adding a separating period.

But there's also `TO_CHAR`:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('20140328160335880258', 'yyyymmddhh24missff6')
```